# I have to (Project > clean) everytime I want to run. How not to?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing a project with some colleagues using Java. After 1 month of working, suddenly almost all of us (the ones that mainly use eclipse as an IDE) got a weird problem : when we run the code, we run a previous version of it. You can imagine the confusion that appeared among us since the bad code was still running despite the good code written afterwards. We found a solution : Project > Clean in the Eclipse toolbar. Believe it or not but every time I have to add one line of code and run, I have to clean before. It becomes frustrating.

Here are my questions : is there something I can do to stop doing that every-time I want to run the code (like an automatic clean)? Why does it have this behaviour ? Why my colleagues that use IntelliJ don't have that problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Go to project menu and select build automatically.

Comment: Is Eclipse building the code, or is it invoking another tool to do it? Is the project located on a local disk for everyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are doing something more complicated than you let on, check Project > Build Automatically. This does what it says. If it is off, then you will have to do Project > Build All (or, Clean) manually.

If Build Automatically is checked, then your team may have done something to the project configuration that is affecting the build process.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't recall unchecking Project > Build Automatically.

Comment: In fact, it does Save + Clean + Run in one click on the green arrow . . . What a boon !